# Python CPU time on windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, time

I am looking for a way to measure the CPU time of the part of my python program. I was looking around and it seems all the time measuring functions that I could find measure the wall clock time on windows. Is there a way to measure the CPU time on windows for python ? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**time.process_time()**

https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0418/

> The new time.process_time() function acts as a portable counter that
> always measures CPU time (excluding time elapsed during sleep) and has
> the best available resolution.

**Earlier answer** for anyone wanting to use timeit() to **average**:

I wrote this while recently learning Python. It's a [timeit.Timer](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/timeit.html) class iterating **timeit()** over functions for averaging; in my research timing seemed to be easy to mess up and timeit() apparently tricky to get working (though easier to get working on command line). This works.

Also note this answer suggests the best bet is [time.process_time()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html) for Python 3.3+ and reminds that .default_timer() is wall time:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15176730/3981745

```
""" Sum a range with timing/comparisons.

    - Manually summing from low..high : a beginner's loop with no algorithms experience
    - Python's sum() - does the same thing for an "efficient" programmer
    - Fast sum - a programmer with math focus 
    - Timing calls (easy to do wrong)
    
    This is a trivial formula to demonstrate what a little math can do; for games this type of optimization is critical. It could probably be even more optimized.
"""

def slow_way(lo, hi):
    s=0
    for i in range(lo, hi+1):
        s+=i
    return s
    
def fast_way(lo, hi):
    lph=lo+hi        # lo plus hi
    hmlpo=hi-lo+1    # hi minus lo plus one
    pairs=hmlpo//2
    
    #print("-", lo,hi,pairs, pairs*lph, (lo+pairs)*(hmlpo%2))
    
    return (pairs*lph + (lo+pairs)*(hmlpo%2))

import timeit
# 'builtin' hack doesn't seem to work
#import __builtin__
#__builtin__.__dict__.update(locals()) 

ranges=[]
ranges.append((1,10,))
ranges.append((2,10,))
ranges.append((3,10,))
ranges.append((4,10,))
ranges.append((5,10,))
ranges.append((32,10032,))

print("Calculation check...")
print("slow : sum : fast : should all match")
for tupl in ranges:
    l=tupl[0]; h=tupl[1]
    print("{} : {} : {}".format(slow_way(l,h), sum(range(l, h+1)), fast_way(l,h)))

iters=100000
print("-"*20 +"\nTime compare ({} iterations) : lower is better".format(iters))
slow=timeit.Timer("slow_way(1,101)", "from __main__ import slow_way")
print("slow: {0:.6f}".format(slow.timeit(number=iters)))

# functions include last number, range should be +1
s=timeit.Timer("sum(range(1,102))", "")
print(" sum: {0:.6f}".format(s.timeit(number=iters)))

fast=timeit.Timer("fast_way(1,101)", "from __main__ import fast_way")
print("  fast: {0:.6f}".format(fast.timeit(number=iters)))
```

Output

```
Calculation check...
slow : sum : fast : should all match
55 : 55 : 55
54 : 54 : 54
52 : 52 : 52
49 : 49 : 49
45 : 45 : 45
50325032 : 50325032 : 50325032
--------------------
Time compare (100000 iterations) : lower is better
slow: 4.719885
 sum: 0.963886
  fast: 0.343524
```

Comment: I don't mind your edits...or I can remove the extraneous myself if people think that's better.

Answer (score 0):

**time.clock()**

On windows you can use `time.clock()` which basically uses `QueryPerformanceCounter()` from the Windows API.

QueryPerformanceCounter():

> Retrieves the current value of the performance counter, which is a high resolution (<1us) time stamp that can be used for time-interval measurements.

Here is a detailed explanation for time.clock from the python docs:

> On Unix, return the current processor time as a floating point number expressed in seconds. The precision, and in fact the very definition of the meaning of “processor time”, depends on that of the C function of the same name, but in any case, this is the function to use for benchmarking Python or timing algorithms.
>   On Windows, this function returns wall-clock seconds elapsed since the first call to this function, as a floating point number, based on the Win32 function QueryPerformanceCounter(). The resolution is typically better than one microsecond.

**timeit**

If you need something even more accurate there is `timeit`. This answer explains the benefits of `timeit`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17579466/2394967

Comment: Here is the problem. I am currently using timeit with this functions. start_time = timeit.default_timer() elapsed = (timeit.default_timer() - start_time). But when I put pause in between these, it still counts the pause time as well. Isnt this makes it into a wall clock timer instead of CPU timer ?

Comment: but time.clock() gives me a wall clock as well and it seems like it will give CPU time only when used on Unix. How do I get it to give me CPU time on windows :)

Comment: Verifying timeit's clock choices...in the meantime what about  https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html : process_time()

Comment: Ok, process_time() seem to give the desired result. Documentation states that it gives the sum of the system and user CPU time, which works for me. Thank you.

Comment: and `QueryPerformanceCounter` in turn is a hi-res __wall__ clock