# CPU usage of python script

Tags: python, linux, console

Is it possible to check CPU usage of simple script ?

For example: How to get the CPU usage in % of printing 100 times "hello world!" ?

Currently I'm getting the execution time in the console, by:

```
time -p python script.py
```

Comment: so? what do you want that "time" don't let you?

Comment: Is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15176619/timing-the-cpu-time-of-a-python-program what you are looking for?

Comment: You can look at the `top` unix command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need the psutil module.

```
import psutil
print(psutil.cpu_percent())
```

Comment: `psutil.cpu_percent` is for the whole system, not an individual process. For just the current script, use `current_process = psutil.Process();` `print(current_process.cpu_percent())`.

Comment: how to get cpu usage in each seconds

Comment: Complementary to @ErykSun answer. Warning the first time this method is called with interval = 0.0 or None it will return a meaningless 0.0 value which you are supposed to ignore. The second call is just fine :).

Answer (score 3):

If you are on a unix machine, you could always open `top` in a new terminal and then observe the % usage while you run your python program. Alternatively, there are some 3rd party libraries you can use.

Here's one: `Benchmark`

Examples (taken from the [py package index](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Benchmarker/4.0.1)).

Program:

```
from benchmarker import Benchmarker

## specify number of loop
with Benchmarker(1000*1000, width=20) as bench:
    s1, s2, s3, s4, s5 = "Haruhi", "Mikuru", "Yuki", "Itsuki", "Kyon"

    @bench(None)                ## empty loop
    def _(bm):
        for i in bm:
            pass

    @bench("join")
    def _(bm):
        for i in bm:
            sos = ''.join((s1, s2, s3, s4, s5))

    @bench("concat")
    def _(bm):
        for i in bm:
            sos = s1 + s2 + s3 + s4 + s5

    @bench("format")
    def _(bm):
        for i in bm:
            sos = '%s%s%s%s%s' % (s1, s2, s3, s4, s5)
```

Results:

```
$ python example.py -h              # show help
$ python example.py -o result.json
## benchmarker:         release 4.0.0 (for python)
## python version:      3.4.2
## python compiler:     GCC 4.8.2
## python platform:     Linux-3.13.0-36-generic-x86_64-with-debian-jessie-sid
## python executable:   /opt/vs/python/3.4.2/bin/python
## cpu model:           Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2670 v2 @ 2.50GHz  # 2494.050 MHz
## parameters:          loop=1000000, cycle=1, extra=0

##                        real    (total    = user    + sys)
(Empty)                 0.0236    0.0200    0.0200    0.0000
join                    0.2779    0.2800    0.2800    0.0000
concat                  0.3792    0.3800    0.3800    0.0000
format                  0.4233    0.4300    0.4300    0.0000

## Ranking                real
join                    0.2779  (100.0) ********************
concat                  0.3792  ( 73.3) ***************
format                  0.4233  ( 65.6) *************

## Matrix                 real    [01]    [02]    [03]
[01] join               0.2779   100.0   136.5   152.3
[02] concat             0.3792    73.3   100.0   111.6
[03] format             0.4233    65.6    89.6   100.0
```

Comment: Can you provide another example including the `if __name__ == '__main__':` part ?

Answer (score -1):

**This will not calculate the CPU usage, but the execution time.** 
Use `timeit` and find the difference in the initial time of the execution and the end of the program. For example:

```
import timeit
start_time = timeit.default_timer()
print("Hello World")
print("Hello World")
print("Hello World")
end_time = timeit.default_timer()
print (end_time - start_time)
```

Comment: Question asked is not about finding execution time, Its about evaluating CPU utilization.

Comment: @MayurMahajan, Thanks, I just edited my answer to reflect what it actually does.