# Why BasicEngine.RunInference gets stuck on child process

Tags: python, tensorflow, multiprocessing, tensorflow-lite, google-coral

I am trying to execute the RunInference method of a BasicEngine object on a separate process using the multiprocessing module. It looks like it enters in a deadlock, but I don't know why. My final objective is to get the CPU usage profile of the RunInference method.

I am trying to run it on a RaspberryPi3B+ with a Coral Accelerator and Python 3.5. The RunInference method is correctly executed when the BasicEngine is instanciated in the same process.

```py
from edgetpu.classification.engine import BasicEngine
import random
import numpy as np
import psutil
import time
import multiprocessing as mp

#Code inspired from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49197916/how-to-profile-cpu-usage-of-a-python-script
def run_on_another_process(target, args=(), kwargs={}):
    worker_process = mp.Process(target=target, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    worker_process.start()
    p = psutil.Process(worker_process.pid)

    while worker_process.is_alive():
        #Do something in the parent, e.g., measure the CPU percentage
        print("[Parent] CPU PERCENT: " + str(p.cpu_percent()))
        time.sleep(0.1)

    worker_process.join()

#Loading model
model_path = "<path_to_model>/inception_v1_224_quant_edgetpu.tflite"
engine = BasicEngine(model_path)
print("Engine and model ready!")

#Prepare data
input_size = engine.required_input_array_size()
data = np.array([random.randint(0, 255) for _ in range(input_size)], dtype=np.uint8)

#Infernce on another process
run_on_another_process(engine.RunInference, args=(data,))
```

The method looks like it is in a deadlock. If I fire a KeybordInterrupt I get these errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/<path_to_script>/script.py", line 31, in <module>
    run_on_another_process(lambda data: engine.RunInference(data), args=(data,))
  File "/<path_to_script>/script.py", line 17, in run_on_another_process
    time.sleep(0.1)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Then, I get

```
Error in atexit._run_exitfuncs:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/popen_fork.py", line 29, in poll
    pid, sts = os.waitpid(self.pid, flag)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Any help would be really helpful!

### Edit #1:

Here in the following a working example when both the BasicEngine and the RunInference methods are called on the same process. The parent process prints a limited number of messages.

```py
from edgetpu.classification.engine import BasicEngine
import random
import numpy as np
import psutil
import time
import multiprocessing as mp

def child_func():
    #Loading model
    model_path = "<path_to_model>/inception_v1_224_quant_edgetpu.tflite"
    engine = BasicEngine(model_path)
    print("[Child] Engine and model ready!")
    #Prepare data
    input_size = engine.required_input_array_size()
    data = np.array([random.randint(0, 255) for _ in range(input_size)], dtype=np.uint8)
    engine.RunInference(data)

def run_on_another_process(target, args=(), kwargs={}):
    worker_process = mp.Process(target=target, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    worker_process.start()
    p = psutil.Process(worker_process.pid)


    while worker_process.is_alive():
        #Do something in the parent, e.g., measure the CPU percentage
        print("[Parent] CPU PERCENT: " + str(p.cpu_percent()))
        time.sleep(0.1)

    worker_process.join()

#Run on another process
run_on_another_process(child_func)
```

Comment: I tried to reproduce this issue. For me it is continuously printing ""[Parent] CPU PERCENT: 0.0 ". Is this what you are referring to a deadlock ? Did you also try to run another demo in loop which performs inferences on an image ?

Comment: That message is printed by the Parent process and it is expected, but it should print only a few messages since the RunInference call should be quite fast. The problem is with the Child process that looks it is blocked and the parent waits. I added an example (Edit #1) that works when the child process is executes both the BasicEngine instantiation and the RunInference method.