# psutil.cpu_percent() showing 0.0 as script of from cmd-line but works as intended from interpreter

Tags: python, cpu-usage, psutil

> python -c "import psutil;print(psutil.cpu_percent())"

Output: 0.0

> python # we're in the interpreter now
>
> import psutil
>
> print(psutil.cpu_percent())

output: 12.7

what's going on here? when running it outside of the interpreter I always get either 0.0 or 100.0 so I assume it's reporting only itself's cpu usage percentage in this case.

But I'm curious as to why and how the same code isn't acting consitently as a script vs being executed in the interpreter.

Found the 'expected behavior' of the lib here: [CPU usage of python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44637844/cpu-usage-of-python-script)

Comment: try to run it an a loop to get more than just one value

Comment: Give the process a little time to allow measurable runtime: `python -c "import psutil;print(psutil.cpu_percent(0.1))"` and read the red warning at https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#psutil.Process.cpu_percent .

Comment: Adding an interval is exactly what 'fixes' this.
Although I am rather curious as to why this happens.